# How does this star1 variation work? (star1 is a stochastic (dice) algorithm for artificial intelligence in adversarial games)

Tags: artificial-intelligence, board-games

I don't understand how the star1 variation mentioned in the paper is [Sparse Sampling for Adversarial](http://mlanctot.info/files/papers/mcms-ecai-cgw.pdf) different than the usual star1 algorithm?

> (Taken from the bottom of page 7). This variant can be easily
>   described in terms of the descriptions of Star1. To enable sampling,
>   one need only change the implementation of getOutcomeSet on line 5 of
>   Algorithm 1. Instead of generating the full list of moves, the new
>   function samples c outcomes with replacement and assigns a uniform
>   distribution over the new outcome set of size c.

Does the variation only generate some of the possible game states and not all of them?

I think I understand star1 but I don't really understand star2 because it is more complicated. I only have a bachelor's degree in computers and this theoretical stuff is way above my head. Thanks for any help that I get. :)